# FreeQ checking for several variables

Tags: pattern-matching

I am using `FreeQ` to define a replacement rule. However, it doesn't seem to be possible to specify a list of variables as the second argument, which is why I came up with something like this

```
AngleBracket[a_ b_] := 
 a AngleBracket[b] /; (FreeQ[a, x] && FreeQ[a, y] && FreeQ[a, z])
```

Now, for many variables `x,y,z, ...` this becomes very tedious. Is there a better, i.e., shorter way to achieve what I want?

Comment: use `Alternatives` , i.e., `FreeQ[a, x|y|z]`?

Comment: Ah, I wasn't ware of `Alternatives`, thx. Just thought now about sth like this `Apply[And, FreeQ[a, #] & /@ {x, y, z}]`, but this is also rather `dirty`.

Comment: If you have a list of variables, you can do something along the lines of `FreeQ[a, Alternatives@@{x, y, z, f, g, h, j ...}]`

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {x,y,z};
```

You can use `Alternatives@@list` as the second argument of `FreeQ`:

```
FreeQ[x + 2 y + w, Alternatives @@ {x, y, z}]
```

> False

```
FreeQ[5 + u v w, Alternatives @@ list]
```

> True

Alternatively, you can map `FreeQ[a, #]&` on `list`:

```
And @@ (FreeQ[x + 2 y + w, #] & /@ list)
```

> False

```
And @@ (FreeQ[5 + u v w, #] & /@ list)
```

> True